# How do I Query a child value of an object in a CharField of a model?

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class OAuthCredentials(BaseModel):

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="credentials_author")
    temp_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
    credentials = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

The "credentials" CharField is an object with a token and some other info inside of it.

I'm trying to authenticate the token like so:

```
def authenticate(request, username=None, password=None, token=None, **kwargs):

    if token:
        if request.session['credentials']['token'] == token:
            user = OAuthCredentials.objects.get(credentials__token=token)
```

I thought I could look inside of it to query like so:
`user = OAuthCredentials.objects.get(credentials__token=token)`

But I'm getting the error:
`Unsupported lookup 'token' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.`

How do I check my token against the token inside of the credentials object in that model?

Comment: how is that stored? As a JSON blob? If this is not a postgreSQL database, then JSON lookups are not supported.

Comment: Can you share an example of one of your credentials? Your model is `Creds`, but you're using `OAuthCredentials` is that correct?

Comment: Yes, using PostgreSQL. I'm not sure what's it's saved as, honestly. I get this on print: `<google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials object at 0x000001B6FF7826C8>`. I fixed the model name.

Comment: with `print(vars(credentials)` I get `{'token': '<token_value_here>', etc.}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a CharField. If you store all information as a string in there, but only want to compare tokens, you're going to have a hard time. Basics of normalization: if you want to compare apples, store apples, not fruit.

Either compare credentials with credentials:

```py
user = OauthCredentials.objects.get(credentials=str(request.session['credentials']))
```

Or store the token and compare the token:

```py
# On authentication:
OauthCredentials.objects.update_or_create(author=request.user, token=credentials['token'])

# On verification:
user = OauthCredentials.objects.get(token=request.session['credentials']['token'])
```

Comment: I decided to take your suggestion and just added a token field as well as the credential field. However, although I understand what you're saying, what about the idea of ForeignKeys? You are essentially relating to an object for use in various ways in your templates or server code. Wouldn't that same principle apply here where an object is being held in the CharField?